duckdb - can't insert data due to constraint, but also there is no constraint
I have a table in postgres that I want to use duckdb to insert into. I have a unique constraint on the table that uses multiple columns to determine a unique row. On conflict, the duplicate rows should be ignored.
Here is the code I use to set it up (in a class but doesn't make a difference)
self.conn = duckdb.connect()
self.conn.install_extension('postgres')
self.conn.load_extension('postgres')
self.conn.sql("ATTACH 'dbname=player_data user=postgres host=127.0.0.1 password=mypassword' AS postgres (TYPE POSTGRES);")

If I run this
r = self.conn.sql('''
    INSERT INTO postgres.ranked.ranked_data
    SELECT * FROM 'data/*.json';
''')

print(r)

it gives me this error
duckdb.duckdb.Error: Failed to copy data: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_row"
DETAIL:  Key (leagueid, queuetype, tier, rank, leaguepoints)=(766896e1-2b75-450f-acd4-083d5ef60b55, RANKED_SOLO_5x5, DIAMOND, I, 50) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY ranked_data, line 45

If I add an ON CONFLICT statement
r = self.conn.sql('''
    INSERT INTO postgres.ranked.ranked_data
    SELECT * FROM 'data/*.json'
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
''')

print(r)

It gives me this error
duckdb.duckdb.BinderException: Binder Error: There are no UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY Indexes that refer to this table, ON CONFLICT is a no-op

So according to duckdb, it can't insert because there is a constraint but also there is no constraint at the same time. Help me make this make sense please!

You didn't specify the column names in ON CONFLICT. So, ON CONFLICT (leagueid, queuetype, tier, rank, leaguepoints) DO NOTHING

I imagine you could reference the constraint by name too - unique_row but I have no way of testing any of this

Neither of those worked unfortunately. This also wouldn't be the case because in duckdb (and postgres too?) you can do INSERT OR IGNORE INTO, which is the same as DO NOTHING

In Postgres it would work if you had a composite index that was unique

Add the table definition of postgres.ranked.ranked_data as text update to your question.

See Issue #189. Seems UPSERTS are not supported. For what is supported see Postgres extension starting at Below is a list of supported operations.

That should be Issue #189.

From here:
https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/postgres

The postgres_execute Function
The postgres_execute function allows running arbitrary queries within Postgres, including statements that update the schema and content of the database.


ATTACH 'dbname=postgresscanner' AS postgres_db (TYPE POSTGRES);
CALL postgres_execute('postgres_db', 'CREATE TABLE my_table (i INTEGER)');


Warning
This function is only available on DuckDB v0.10.1+, using the latest Postgres extension. To upgrade your extension, run FORCE INSTALL postgres;.

You will need to be using DuckDB v0.10.1+ and upgrade extension to latest, then:
duckdb.connect()
con = duckdb.connect()
con.install_extension('postgres')
con.load_extension('postgres')
con.sql("ATTACH 'dbname=test user=postgres host=127.0.0.1' AS postgres (TYPE POSTGRES);")

con.sql("create table postgres.duckdb_test (id integer primary key, fld varchar)")
con.commit()
con.sql("insert into postgres.duckdb_test values (1, 'dog'), (2, 'cat')")
con.commit()

con.sql("""CALL postgres_execute('postgres', "insert into duckdb_test values (1, 'fish') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id")""")
Out[29]: 
┌─────────┐
│ Success │
│ boolean │
├─────────┤
│ 0 rows  │
└─────────┘

Which from the Postgres log shows:
2024-05-13 10:09:40.048 PDT [16512] postgres@test LOG:  statement: BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
    insert into duckdb_test values (1, 'fish') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id
2024-05-13 10:09:40.048 PDT [16512] postgres@test LOG:  statement: COMMIT



